# iOS GMSPlacesClient: Whether or not the search results affected by the type of Google Maps account?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am trying to search place using `GMSPlacesClient` `autocompleteQuery` by keyword within a specified city or country. My Google Map account is Standard with enabled billing.

**Code**

```
GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = [GMSMapShareInstance sharedInstance].projection.visibleRegion;
    GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:visibleRegion.nearLeft
                                                                       coordinate:visibleRegion.nearRight];
    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterGeocode;
    filter.country = @"US";
    GMSPlacesClient *placesClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];
    [placesClient autocompleteQuery:searchTerms
                              bounds:bounds
                              filter:filter
                            callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                                if (error != nil) {
                                    NSLog(@"Search error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                    return;
                                }

                                arrSearchedResult = results;
                                [self.tblSearchResult reloadData];
                            }];
```

But it returns results that are seem not exactly. I don't know whether it's  affected by account type (Standard, Premium) or not.

Anyone experienced a similar issue? Or have any way to improve search result?

Thanks in advance!

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: Account Type should not be a factor for it. Do you have a sample result that you can share? You can check out the [Places Autocomplete for iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) documentation to see if you missed anything. My take on it is that you should have used `kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterRegion` instead of `kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterGeocode` to filter out results within the said type (city/country)

Comment: @adjuremods I am not be able to get more than 5 results, sometime get only 1 result